# modify script code on code pen that author didnt tell how to modify

Tags: javascript, php, web

I wanna make a wheel of fortune for my game, I found a good code on `Code Pen`

The link is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzJXwo).

I dont learn more about `JS`, so i dont know how I can modify the number of item in wheel and label for each of them
Thanks much for evey help from you

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Can you help me modify javascript in above code pen link ? I wanna modify the number of items in wheel of fortune and label of each

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what that code is supposed to do as it has an error on `p.update();` (p is the string 'dawd'.

I think the amount of segments can be defined here:

```
wheel = new Wheel(wheelX, wheelY, wheelRadius, 32, 0.25, 7.5);
```

Change the number 32 to what you would like.